# php artisan migrate, access denied for user'homestead'@'172.21.0.1'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, artisan-migrate

when I ran `php artisan migrate` this results to (see screenshot below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8B1B.png)

I tried doing

- `composer dump-autoload -o`
- `php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan config:clear` `php artisan route:clear`
- then tried `php artisan migrate` again

but nothing happens. mysql-1 container is perfectly running on docker. For reference, this is my .env
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnEAR.png)

I also tried removing the quote on username and password, also tried this

```
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

but still having the same error.

Also, for reference this is my docker-compose.yml

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '8000:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - minio
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:5.7.16'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    minio:
        image: 'minio/minio:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MINIO_PORT:-9000}:9000'
            - '${FORWARD_MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT:-8900}:8900'
        environment:
            MINIO_ROOT_USER: 'sail'
            MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-minio:/data/minio'
        networks:
            - sail
        command: minio server /data/minio --console-address ":8900"
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sail-minio:
        driver: local
```

Comment: show us your `docker-compose.yml` if exist

Comment: `docker-compose exec laravel.test ping mysql` try this and see works

Comment: If you're using sail you need to run `sail artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DB hostname in your .env file as the name of the mysql container.
i.e. if the name of databse container is xyz-db-1
use DB_HOST=xyz-db-1

Answer (score 0):

A connection to the user "homestead" may not be allowed from this IP address. You can check which host is set to that particular user by connecting to your mysql server and running query `select Host,User from mysql.user`.
If that IP address is not in the host column, you can try alternating your user to allow connections from any IP address using:

`ALTER USER 'homestead'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password'`

or if you want to allow connections only from that IP address use:

```
ALTER USER 'homestead'@'172.21.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password'
```